# How to know if the argument that is passed to the function is a class, union or enum in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, enums, template-meta-programming

I want to define an operator<< for all enums, to cout the value and print that it is an enum like this:

code:

```
enum AnyEnum{A,B,C};
AnyEnum enm = A;
cout << enm <<endl;
```

output:

```
This is an enum which has a value equal to 0
```

I know a way of doing this with Boost library by using **is_enum** struct. But I don’t  understand how it works. So that's why, in general, I am interested how to identify if the veriable is a class type, union type or an enum (in compile time).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Determining class types you could use the fact that member pointers exist

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct issame { };

template<typename A>
struct issame<A, A> { typedef void type; };

template<typename> struct tovoid { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct isclass { static bool const value = false; };

template<typename C>
struct isclass<C, typename tovoid<int C::*>::type> {
  static bool const value = true;
};
```

You cannot detect the difference of an union and a non-union class. At least I don't know how, and boost doesn't know either.

I think detecting enums could work by making sure `T` isn't a class, function or integral type, and then trying to assign to an integral type. You could

```
template<typename E, typename = void> 
struct isenum { 
  struct No { char x; };
  struct Yes { No n1; No n2; };

  struct nullsink {};
  static No checkI(nullsink*); // accept null pointer constants
  static Yes checkI(...);

  static Yes checkE(int);
  static No checkE(...);

  static bool const value = (sizeof(checkI(E())) == sizeof(Yes)) && 
                            (sizeof(checkE(E())) == sizeof(Yes));
};

// class
template<typename E>
struct isenum<E, typename tovoid<int E::*>::type> {
  static bool const value = false;
};

// reference
template<typename R>
struct isenum<R&, void> {
  static bool const value = false;
};

// function (FuntionType() will error out).
template<typename F>
struct isenum<F, typename issame<void(F), void(F*)>::type> {
  static bool const value = false;
};

// array (ArrayType() will error out)
template<typename E>
struct isenum<E[], void> {
  static bool const value = false;
};
template<typename E, int N>
struct isenum<E[N], void> {
  static bool const value = false;
};
```

Quick & dirty test (works on GCC/clang/comeau):

```
enum A { };
struct B { };
typedef int &C;
typedef void D();
typedef int E;
typedef long F;
typedef int const G;
typedef int H[1];

template<typename T, bool E>
struct confirm { typedef char x[(T::value == E) ? 1 : -1]; };

int main() {
  confirm< isenum<A>, true >();
  confirm< isenum<B>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<C>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<D>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<E>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<F>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<G>, false >();
  confirm< isenum<H>, false >();
}
```

Comment: what does `(void) sizeof(x)` mean? :-/

Comment: @Nawaz : It (casting to `void`) is just to suppress the returned value. :)

Comment: @Prasoon : hehe..that's what I thought at first.. but then it came to mind that since it's Johannes, maybe he meant something else which I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Nawaz what @Prasoon says :) I've simplified `main` so it doesn't use these things anymore now.

Comment: previous things looked geeky. you should've kept it there.:P

Answer (score 3):

> I am interested how to identify if the veriable is a class type, union type or an enum (in compile time).

[boost::type_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Even [C++ TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) has got a `<type_traits>` header to support that functionality. In C++0x everything's gonna be a lot better.

For example the following machinery makes use of [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to check whether the argument passed is a class type:

```
template<typename T>struct Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type
{
    template<typename C> static char func (char C::*p);
    template<typename C> static long func (...);
    enum{val = CHECKER(func,Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type)};
};
```

The MACRO `CHECKER` is

```
#define CHECKER(func_name,class_name) \
sizeof(class_name<T>::template func_name<T>(0)) == 1
```

To understand how type_traits work you need to have some basic knowledge of templates including [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) and SFINAE.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Please explain me how this structs work? For example is_enum.

Comment: @Narek : You need to understand how templates work and fundamentals related to template metaprogramming and SFINAE.

Comment: Ok, I am familar with some concepts. SO How your example identifies if T is a class or no?

Comment: @Narek : Non class types don't have pointers to members. That should give some hint.

Comment: It is almost clear, except first function argument (char C::*p). What if I have defined a class like this: class Test{ int member_}; and as a template patam "T" I use "Test" then what is "char C::*p" for that case?

Comment: If the "C" in "char C::*p" is the class Test, then what is "C::*p"?

Comment: `Test::*p` which is valid...but if your `C` is `int` you'd get `int::*p` which is certainly erroneous. So the substitution fails but its not an error..

Comment: What is Test::*p? I don't have a static pointer variable named "p" in class Test...

Comment: @Narek : It is a declaration (`p` : formal parameter). You need to brush up your C++ a bit.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't understand if it is a declaration the you should write either (char * p) or (C *p), isn't it?

Comment: @Narek : Not if `p` is declared to be a pointer to a member of a class.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: You mean that class C is defined like this?: class C {public: char * p; .........};

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with compiler hooks. The compiler has special functions that "fill" the template with the apropriate value (at least in C++0x where type_traits has been standardized).
For instance the `is_pod` trait uses the `__is_pod` compiler hook under VC 10 to get the apropriate information.

Answer (score -3):

its not possible to know the variable type at compile time.