# is_enum implementation

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

I'm trying to implement `std::is_enum`. Here is my code so far:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_enum {
    static bool value;
};

template<typename T>
bool is_enum<T>::value = false;

template<enum E>
struct is_enum {
    static bool value;
};

template<enum E>
bool is_enum<E>::value = true;
```

This code causes error. More precisely:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -o "enum2" "enum2.cpp" (in directory: /home/aristophanes/Desktop/C++)
Compilation failed.
enum2.cpp:11:15: error: use of enum ‘E’ without previous declaration
enum2.cpp:3:10: error: template parameter ‘class T’
enum2.cpp:12:8: error: redeclared here as ‘int E’
enum2.cpp:16:15: error: use of enum ‘E’ without previous declaration
enum2.cpp:17:14: error: ‘E’ was not declared in this scope
enum2.cpp:17:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
enum2.cpp:17:18: error: template declaration of ‘bool value’
```

Can anyone explain to me where I make a mistake? It is mine or the compiler's fault? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** if it is completely wrong, then how can I correct it?

**Note:** I'm using `g++ -o <file> <file>.cpp`

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `is_enum`, like many other type traits, cannot be implemented without compiler intrinsics.

Comment: [OT] In this case, a better alternative to static variables can be _enums_ (like: `enum { value = false };`)

Comment: @Gigi : This is tagged `c++11` -- the _best_ alternative is to inherit from `std::true_type`, `std::false_type`, or `std::integral_constant<>`. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn that is incorrect (at least for C++03 and I'm pretty sure the same is true about C++11). An implementation is given in "C++ Templates, the complete guide", and I provided an alternative definition in one of my answers (which is far less elegant, but passed all my tests), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705316/how-to-know-if-the-argument-that-is-passed-to-the-function-is-a-class-union-or

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  In C++11 [meta.rqmts]/p1 requires `std::is_enum` to derive publicly and unambiguously from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant ah I see. I should have mentioned that the code I linked to is not an implementation of is_enum. It is only intended to show a possible implementation technique to be used by one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to implement this is to use compiler magic, and I believe most implementations do this.

For example, here's libc++'s implementation for gcc >= 4.3 and any compiler that `__has_feature(is_enum)`<sup>1</sup>

```
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_VISIBLE is_enum
    : public integral_constant<bool, __is_enum(_Tp)> {};
```

For all other compilers libc++ does:

```
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_VISIBLE is_enum
    : public integral_constant<bool, !is_void<_Tp>::value             &&
                                     !is_integral<_Tp>::value         &&
                                     !is_floating_point<_Tp>::value   &&
                                     !is_array<_Tp>::value            &&
                                     !is_pointer<_Tp>::value          &&
                                     !is_reference<_Tp>::value        &&
                                     !is_member_pointer<_Tp>::value   &&
                                     !is_union<_Tp>::value            &&
                                     !is_class<_Tp>::value            &&
                                     !is_function<_Tp>::value         > {};
```

Some of those other type traits still require compiler magic.<sup>2</sup> E.g. `is_union`. However, that condition can be rewritten such that it doesn't need compiler magic. This can be done by replacing the seperate checks for unions and classes with a single check for both, as Johannes Schaub points out.

<sub>1. So far as I know only clang implements `__has_feature`, unfortunately.</sub>
<sub>2. It's interesting that libc++ does have a version of `is_union<T>` and `is_class<T>` that do not use compiler intrinsics, but as a result they provide erroneous results for union types. But their erroneous results are complementary so libc++'s fallback implementation of `is_enum<T>` provides accurate results.</sub>

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. In the alternative definition, you can replace `!is_union<_Tp> && !is_class<_Tp>` by `!is_union_or_class<_Tp>`, which is pretty straightforward to implement without compiler-intrinsics by trying to form a member pointer and relying on SFINAE. All the other type traints mentioned there can be written without intrinsics support too.

Comment: @Johannes : Ah, `is_union_or_class` didn't occur to me. Good stuff.

Comment: @bames53:  Your description of when libc++ uses this definition is inverted.  libc++ uses this definition for gcc < 4.3 or does not have __has_feature(is_enum).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  "Incorrect" is a bit harsh.  Without compiler help `is_union<T>::value` is typically always false, and is_class<T>::value is typically true for a union type (unions and classes are indistinguishable without compiler help).  In that context `!is_union<_Tp> && !is_class<_Tp>` is exactly equivalent to  `!is_union_or_class<_Tp>`.  That being said, getting compiler help (typically spelled __is_enum(T)) is definitely the way to go if it is available.

Comment: @HowardHinnant ah I see now, I didn't know it works that nicely here with your definition. Though it looks to me that it was a bit too "unharsh" because his earlier statement that it cannot be done without compiler help (and as evidence showing your libc++ code) would be more incorrect than more correct because as you say it works correct even without compiler help :) I agree that using compiler-intrinsics is the better way to go in any way.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I'm mentioning both implementations, but the first one is so short and simple that it's easy to skip over. I believe my answer already reflects that libc++ uses a fallback only for gcc<4.3 and other compilers for which `__has_feature(is_enum)` is not true.

Comment: @bames53:  I see now.  I misread your words.  You have it exactly right! :-)

Comment: The clang libcxx non-magic implementation is incorrect, if the compiler has built-in nullptr(in this case likely the 'magic' version is selected). one way to fix it is to add `&& !is_null_pointer<T>::value` (c++14). I know this trait is in C++14, but, in the latest libcxx source code, it is still not fixed.

Comment: GCC's libstdc++ has `__has_builtin` which works exactly the same as clang's `__has_feature`. Try `static_assert(__has_builtin(__is_enum))`.

Answer (score 9):

This

```
template<enum E>
```

promises that the template argument is a *value* of type `enum E`.  The argument is NOT a type (Type template arguments are introduced by `typename`, or for backward compatibility, `class`.  Even `struct` isn't allowed).  It's just like saying

```
template<int i>
```

except no name is given for the variable.

Things go wrong from there.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: No, you need a compiler builtin operator, like ildjarn said in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that

```
template<enum E>
```

Is interpreted as unnamed parameter with type forward declared enum named `E`.
Semantically same to

```
template<int>
```

Just substituting `int` with `enum E`.