# boost::is_enum how it works?

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits

I've interesting how this thing is work on theory.
Example:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_enum.hpp>
#include <iostream>

enum foo 
{
    AAA,
    BBB
};

typedef foo bar;

struct sfoo {
    enum bar {
        CCC
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << boost::is_enum<foo>::value << "\n";        // 1
    std::cout << boost::is_enum<bar>::value << "\n";        // 1
    std::cout << boost::is_enum<sfoo>::value << "\n";       // 0
    std::cout << boost::is_enum<int>::value << "\n";        // 0
    std::cout << boost::is_enum<sfoo::bar>::value << "\n";  // 1
    return 0;
}
```

I try to explore source code but it was too hard (macros + templates code navigation fails). Someone can get theory exploration how it works? I've have no ideas how it can be implemented.

Comment: This has already been asked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705316/how-to-know-if-the-argument-that-is-passed-to-the-function-is-a-class-union-or

Comment: Thanks, seems i use bad search request before create question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running into a lot of macros because Boost is switching between compiler intrinsics for all the platforms it supports. For instance, Visual C++ defines `__is_enum(T)` which will returns `true` if `T` is an `enum` and `false` otherwise. MSDN has a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194.aspx) of such intrinsics that Visual C++ implements for type trait support.

[`is_enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) is now part of C++11, and is included in the `type_traits` header. Looking through your standard library implementation will most likely be easier than the Boost headers.

**EDIT:**
I found the Boost implementation; it is located in `<boost_path>\boost\type_traits\intrinsics.hpp`. Search this file for `BOOST_IS_ENUM` in this file and you'll see the compiler intrinsic implemented by various compilers. Interestingly enough, it seems all of them implement this particular one as `__is_enum(T)`.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::is_enum` is implemented like `std::is_enum`. It requires some compiler magic. Check the following link which has the same question, and an implementation: [is_enum implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316912/is-enum-implementation)

Comment: Compiler magic may be the simplest and the best way to implement it, but it isn't necessary, and the Boost implementation works on compilers that don't have the compiler magic.

Answer (score 1):

I've not followed the Boost code in detail, but it seems to be using simple elimination: an enum is something which is not arithmetic (built-in integers and floating point types and pointers), not a reference, not a function, not a class or union and not an array.